# My Django update form is not saving and it is also not showing the instance as a patient from the details the patient uses when they sign up

Tags: python, django, forms

My django project does not recognize the instance of the patient details when I go to that page and it is also not saving the new patient details that I enter, instead I'm brought back to the same page with the new details I have entered. When I press the submit button again the same thing happens (same page with the new details)

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone


class User(AbstractUser): 
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    insurance = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    insuranceID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    current_medication = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    preexisting_medication = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    next_of_kin = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    npi= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    education = models.TextField()
    qualifications = models.TextField()
    places_worked = models.TextField()
    consultation_fee = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue_of_operation = models.CharField(max_length=200)



    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

FORMS.PY

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction
from .models import Patient,Doctor, User



GENDER_CHOICES = (
   ('M', 'Male'),
   ('F', 'Female'),
   ('O','Other')
)

class DoctorSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'DR.'}),max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'number'}),max_length=200)
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    speciality = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    npi = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    education = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    qualifications = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    places_worked = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    consultation_fee = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number'}),max_length=200)
    venue_of_operation = forms.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_doctor = True
        user.save()
        doctor = Doctor.objects.create(user=user)
        doctor.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        doctor.name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        doctor.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
        doctor.gender = self.cleaned_data.get('gender')
        doctor.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        doctor.address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
        doctor.speciality = self.cleaned_data.get('speciality')
        doctor.npi = self.cleaned_data.get('npi')
        doctor.education = self.cleaned_data.get('education')
        doctor.qualifications = self.cleaned_data.get('qualifications')
        doctor.places_worked = self.cleaned_data.get('places_worked')
        doctor.consultation_fee = self.cleaned_data.get('consultation_fee')
        doctor.venue_of_operation = self.cleaned_data.get('venue_of_operation')
        doctor.save()

        return user

class PatientSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    insurance = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    insuranceID = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number'}),max_length=200)
    current_medication = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    preexisting_medication = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    next_of_kin = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_patient = True
        user.save()
        patient = Patient.objects.create(user=user)
        patient.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        patient.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        patient.insurance = self.cleaned_data.get('insurance')
        patient.insuranceID = self.cleaned_data.get('insuranceID')
        patient.address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
        patient.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        patient.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
        patient.gender = self.cleaned_data.get('gender')
        patient.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        patient.current_medication = self.cleaned_data.get('current_medication')
        patient.preexisting_medication = self.cleaned_data.get('preexisting_medication')
        patient.next_of_kin = self.cleaned_data.get('next_of_kin')
        patient.save()
        return user

class PatientUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    insurance = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    insuranceID = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number'}),max_length=200)
    current_medication = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    preexisting_medication = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    next_of_kin = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','insurance','phone','email','date_of_birth','insuranceID','address','gender','current_medication','preexisting_medication','next_of_kin']
        

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_patient = True
        user.save()
        patient = Patient.objects.create(user=user)
        patient.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        
        patient.insurance = self.cleaned_data.get('insurance')
        patient.insuranceID = self.cleaned_data.get('insuranceID')
        patient.address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
        patient.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        patient.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
        patient.gender = self.cleaned_data.get('gender')
        patient.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        patient.current_medication = self.cleaned_data.get('current_medication')
        patient.preexisting_medication = self.cleaned_data.get('preexisting_medication')
        patient.next_of_kin = self.cleaned_data.get('next_of_kin')
        patient.save()
        return user
```

Views.py

```
def conditions(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = PatientUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
       
        if u_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            
            
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = PatientUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        
    context = {'u_form': u_form}
    return render(request, 'patient/medicalconditions.html', context)
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
{% load static %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="{% static '../../static/patient/css/style.css' %}"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/patient/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="../../static/patient/css/fontawesome/css/all.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body style="background-image: url('../../static/patient/images/forest.jpg')">
    <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)">
      <div style="background-color: rgb(11, 11, 46); height: 100px">
        <span class="text-start display-2"
          ><a class="text-decoration-none text-light" href="{% url 'home' %}"
            >AVANI</a
          ></span
        >
        <span class="btn-group float-end clearfix align-items-middle mt-5">
          <a
            href="{% url 'contact' %}"
            class="me-5 float-start text-light text-decoration-none"
            >Contact Us</a
          >
        </span>
      </div>

      <h5 style="margin-left:70px">Medical Information</h5>

      <div
        style="
          background-color: rgba(224, 102, 102, 0.267);
          height: 70%;
          width: 90%;
          margin: auto;
        "
        class="my-3 rounded"
      >
        <div style="width: 90%; margin: auto" class="py-3">
          <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.first_name.errors }}
                

                {{ u_form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.insurance.errors }}
                
                {{ u_form.insurance|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.phone.errors }}
                
                {{ u_form.phone|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.email.errors }}
                
                {{ u_form.email|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.date_of_birth.errors }}
                

                {{ u_form.date_of_birth|as_crispy_field }}

              </div>
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.insuranceID.errors }}
                
                {{ u_form.insuranceID|as_crispy_field }}

              </div>
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.address.errors }}
                
                {{ u_form.address|as_crispy_field}}
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                {{ u_form.gender.errors }}
                
                {{ u_form.gender|as_crispy_field }}

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
              {{u_form.current_medication.errors}}
              <div class="mb-3">
                {{u_form.current_medication|as_crispy_field}}
                
              </div>
              {{u_form.preexisting_medication.errors}}
              <div class="mb-3">
                {{u_form.preexisting_medication|as_crispy_field}}
                
              </div>
              {{u_form.next_of_kin.errors}}
              <div class="mb-3">
                {{u_form.next_of_kin|as_crispy_field}}
                
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center mt-3">
              <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="" style="margin-left: 70px;">
        <div class="py-3">

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Logout</button>
        </div>
        <div class="py-3">

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Delete Account</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer
        class="text-center text-lg-start"
        style="background-color: rgb(11, 11, 46)"
      >
        <!-- Grid container -->
        <div class="p-4">
          <!--Grid row-->
          <div class="row">
            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
              <h5 class="text-uppercase text-light">Avani</h5>

              <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="{% url 'contact' %}"
                    >Contact Us</a
                  >
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->

            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
              <h5 class="text-uppercase mb-0 text-light">Insurance</h5>

              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="#!">Britam</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="#!">Britam</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="#!">Britam</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="#!">Britam</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->

            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
              <h5 class="text-uppercase text-light">Specialists</h5>

              <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="#!">Dermatologist</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="#!">Orthodontist</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="text-light" href="#!">Neurosurgeon</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->
          </div>
          <!--Grid row-->
        </div>
        <!-- Grid container -->
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it

```
u_form = PatientUpdateForm(instance=request.user.patient)
```